# onclick inside forEach, value parameter only refers to last element

Tags: javascript

I have a list of anchor in my html, I want to make their href editable.
Everything fine, but the validation step (last onclick) refers to the last anchor instead of the current one

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('.home-content a');

var col = document.querySelectorAll('.home-content > article');

anchors.forEach((k)=> {

    let linkpanel = document.getElementById('link-edit-panel'); //This element is a single div in my html

    let linkpanelvalidate = document.getElementById('validate-link'); //the button inside the said div

    let editinput = linkpanel.querySelector('input'); //the input inside this div

    //For each anchors, I add a button that will let user show the "linkpanel" div to edit the href of this anchor
    let editbut = document.createElement('div');
    let linktxt = k.href;
    editbut.classList.add('edit-but','toremove');
    editbut.innerHTML = "<i class='fas fa-link'></i>";

    //I put this new element to the current anchor
    k.appendChild(editbut);
    console.log(k); // this to show me the full list of anchors

    /* PROBLEM START HERE */
    
    //click on the "edit" button
    editbut.onclick = ()=>{

        console.log(k); //Here, it shows the good anchor!

    }

    //click on the "validate" button
    linkpanelvalidate.onclick = ()=>{

        console.log(k); //Here, it shows the very last anchor...
    }
});
```

I tried to put the element inside a constant

```
const ttt = k;
```

It does not change a thing.

Thank you for your help

Comment: First of all, in your clicks never use your loop items, use `= (event) =>` and then `event.target` to get clicked item. 2. Please make [mre] using <> button in editor to make a fiddle it will help us all help you.

Comment: Is what you meant by `last anchor` is the previous `achor` instead of the current one?

Comment: @ikiK this is already the minimal reproductible example, there is nothing more. I don't use the event object because the onclick is on an element that have nothing to do with the current loop value

Answer (score 0):

We are facing here a classical `forEach` bubbling misunderstand (and I was blind not to see it)

When the click on the validate button occures, the call is made from the "main" bubble (outside the loop function if you need to picture it) so naturaly, it returns the last occurrence of the loop when we print the value in the console for example.

**Solution**

There is many solutions, you can store these values in an array to use each of them later

```
var arr = [];
node.forEach((v)=>{
  arr.push(v);
});
```

Or, you don't want to deal with an array and want to keep it simple, like me, and you create your button during the `forEach` loop event, like this

```
node.forEach((v)=>{
  let btn = document.createElement('button');
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
  btn.onclick = ()=> {
    console.log(v); //it is the current value, not the last one
    //you can create another button here and put his onclick here, the value will still remains etc
  }
});
```